# Kafka Streams: The state store, test.topic.store.1, may have migrated to another instance

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I have this requirement of using kafka streams to aggregate data from two different topics and have a summary as output. The problem is that, the application where this is going to be implemented is meant to run in multiple instances. In each instance we will have to start the streams inorder to query the state store. But because of this I am getting the below error

```
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.InvalidStateStoreException: The state store, test.topic.store.1, may have migrated to another instance.
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.WrappingStoreProvider.stores(WrappingStoreProvider.java:67) ~[kafka-streams-3.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CompositeReadOnlyKeyValueStore.get(CompositeReadOnlyKeyValueStore.java:53) ~[kafka-streams-3.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.example.test.SimpleController.accessStore(SimpleController.java:41) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1732) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

I can understand the gist of things. When I start the streams from the first instance, everything works fine. When I start the streams of the second instance, the partitions are revoked, the stream goes into rebalancing state and then starts running.

```
2022-03-11 18:24:21.638  INFO 23128 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=STREAMS_APP_-e058675d-800a-4c91-8dd3-1f24025f20d5-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=STREAMS_APP_] Adding newly assigned partitions: 
2022-03-11 18:24:21.638  INFO 23128 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread         : stream-thread [STREAMS_APP_-e058675d-800a-4c91-8dd3-1f24025f20d5-StreamThread-1] State transition from STARTING to PARTITIONS_ASSIGNED
2022-03-11 18:24:21.724  INFO 23128 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread         : stream-thread [STREAMS_APP_-e058675d-800a-4c91-8dd3-1f24025f20d5-StreamThread-1] Restoration took 86 ms for all tasks []
2022-03-11 18:24:21.724  INFO 23128 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread         : stream-thread [STREAMS_APP_-e058675d-800a-4c91-8dd3-1f24025f20d5-StreamThread-1] State transition from PARTITIONS_ASSIGNED to RUNNING
2022-03-11 18:24:21.724  INFO 23128 --- [-StreamThread-1] org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams    : stream-client [STREAMS_APP_-e058675d-800a-4c91-8dd3-1f24025f20d5] State transition from REBALANCING to RUNNING
```

But once this happens I am not able to access the state store from both the instances. Ending up with **The state store, test.topic.store.1, may have migrated to another instance** error.
Is there a way that I can rely on to read a KTable from two different instances of the application without the store getting migrated.

The below is the code I am using

Config:

```
@Bean
    public StreamsBuilder simpleKafkaStreamBuilder() throws UnknownHostException {
        final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

        KTable<String, Test> table1 = builder.stream(TEST_TOPIC, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()))
                .groupByKey()
                .aggregate(Test::new, this::aggregateData, materializeStoreV1());

        KTable<String, Test> table2 = builder.stream(TEST_TOPIC, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()))
                .groupByKey()
                .aggregate(Test::new, this::aggregateData, materializeStoreV2());

        return builder;
    }

    private Materialized<String, Test, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>> materializeStoreV1() {
        return Materialized.<String, Test>as(Stores.inMemoryKeyValueStore(TEST_STORE1))
                .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
                .withValueSerde(testSerde());
    }

    private Materialized<String, Test, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>> materializeStoreV2() {
        return Materialized.<String, Test>as(Stores.inMemoryKeyValueStore(TEST_STORE2))
                .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
                .withValueSerde(testSerde());
    }

    private Materialized<String, Test, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>> materializeStoreV3() {
        return Materialized.<String, Test>as(Stores.inMemoryKeyValueStore(TEST_STORE))
                .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
                .withValueSerde(testSerde());
    }

    private Test aggregateData(String key, String value, Test test) {
        test.setKey(key);
        test.incrCount();
        return test;
    }
```

Controller

```
@RestController
public class SimpleController {
    private final StreamsBuilder simpleKafkaStreamBuilder;

    @Autowired
    public SimpleController(StreamsBuilder simpleKafkaStreamBuilder) {
        this.simpleKafkaStreamBuilder = simpleKafkaStreamBuilder;
    }

    @Value("${server.port}")
    private String serverPort;

    private static KafkaStreams kafkaStreams;

    @GetMapping("/start-streams")
    public void startStreams() throws UnknownHostException {
        Properties properties = SimpleKafkaUtil.getDefaultStreamProperties();
        properties.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_SERVER_CONFIG, InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress() + ":" + serverPort);
        properties.put(StreamsConfig.TOPOLOGY_OPTIMIZATION_CONFIG, StreamsConfig.OPTIMIZE);
        kafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(simpleKafkaStreamBuilder.build(), properties);
        System.out.println("[x] stream 1 " + kafkaStreams.toString());
//        kafkaStreams.cleanUp();
        kafkaStreams.start();
    }

    @GetMapping("/access-store/{key}")
    public void accessStore(@PathVariable("key") String key) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("[x] stream 2 " + kafkaStreams.toString());
        while (!kafkaStreams.state().equals(KafkaStreams.State.RUNNING)){
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }

        List<StreamsMetadata> metadataList = (List<StreamsMetadata>) kafkaStreams.streamsMetadataForStore(SimpleKafkaConfig.TEST_STORE1);

        KeyQueryMetadata metadata = kafkaStreams.queryMetadataForKey(SimpleKafkaConfig.TEST_STORE1, key, Serdes.String().serializer());
        System.out.println(" [x] Host: " + metadata.activeHost().host());
        System.out.println(" [x] Host: " + metadata.activeHost().port());

        String hostUri = "http://" + metadata.activeHost().host() + ":" + metadata.activeHost().port();

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        Test test = restTemplate.getForObject(hostUri + "/access-storeV2/" + key, Test.class);
        System.out.println("[x] KEY:" + key);
        System.out.println("[x] VALUE:" + test);
    }

    @GetMapping("/access-storeV2/{key}")
    public Test accessStoreV2(@PathVariable("key") String key) throws InterruptedException{
        System.out.println("[x] stream 2 " + kafkaStreams.toString());
        while (!kafkaStreams.state().equals(KafkaStreams.State.RUNNING)){
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }

        ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<String, Test> store = kafkaStreams.store(StoreQueryParameters.fromNameAndType(SimpleKafkaConfig.TEST_STORE1, QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore()));
        System.out.println("[x] Store KEY:" + key);
        System.out.println("[x] Store VALUE:" + store.get(key));

        return store.get(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at the Interactive Queries feature of Kafka Streams? It describes how to use multiple instances of the application

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks for the reply. Tried looking into the interactive queries feature. There seems to be a provision to add the host and port of an instance into the store-querying metadata using the config 
** 
properties.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_SERVER_CONFIG, InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress() + ":" + serverPort);
**
But something weird is happening, once the streams are started I can only see the metadata for one of the hosts and not the other. any ideas here. By the way I am updating the code with the recent changes.

Comment: Well, `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()` will only return the local server, not query the others. You'll need an [RPC layer for remote connections](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html#querying-remote-state-stores-for-the-entire-app)

Comment: @OneCricketeer I am not just doing  `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()` but `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress() + ":" + serverPort`.
I am checking things by running two instances of the same app in my local machine, one in port1 and another in port2. The problem is that, after I start the streams in both the instances, when I do `streams.allMetadataForStore(storeName)` It is returning details of only one instance, say instance with port1. I am not seeing the instance with port2 in the list.

Comment: Sure, you need the port. My point is that that first part of the server address will only ever be the local server statestore. Is `serverport` the same for both instances? If not, how do you set it?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks for the guidance. it seems like the code is working fine. The reason why I was only getting one host with `streams.allMetadaForStore(storeName)` is, one stream is connecting to both the partitions for that store. So actually the code is working fine.

Comment: And yes, I am using the same host with different ports, something like localhost:8001, localhost:8002 and so on. The problem was, even though both the instances of the application was running, I was only getting localhost:8002 when calling on `streams.allMetadataForStore(storeName)`. Turns out that only localhost:8002 was connected to the store I am trying to access. So it is all fine.

Answer (score 2):

Reference : [Kafka Interactive Queries](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html)

For a multi-instance application setup, if you need to use kafka streams, there is one way to accommodate that setup. Let me get there in a min but first we need to understand what is happening when we start a stream in some application.

When starting a kafka stream over a topic in an application this is what happens.

1. The toplogy for the stream is created, i.e when we try to stream data from a topic, the elements that we configure are attached to the stream in form of nodes. (e.g) If I create a KTable out of a stream, then this KTable is added as a node to the topic topology, hence the name **Topology**
2. The application gets attached to a partition in the topic (now this is important). If there is only one partition in the topic, then you can only attach one instance of the application to it. you can also attach one instance of an application to multiple partitions of a topic. So from this what we understand is that, if we want multiple instances of an application to be connected to a topic through kafka streams, then that particular topic should have a number of partitions that is greater than or equal to the number of instances. That does half the magic. If the number of partitions is less than the number of instances of an application. then one of the instances is going to try and share a partition with another instance and it will end up changing the session details of that partitions and neither of the two instances of application will be able to connect to it. This is what ends up throwing the exception

```
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.InvalidStateStoreException: The state store, store.name, may have migrated to another instance.
```

These are some rules to have a multi-instance kafka stream application.

1. The number of topic partitions should be greater than or equal to the number of instances of application.
2. All the instance of the application should have the same `application.id` in the streams config.
3. We need to add one more config `application.servers = host:port`, this is important.

Once we do this, whenever we start the stream from the instances of the application, the stream stores the server details from `application.servers` in the streams' metadata which we can access using `streams.allMetadataForStore(storeName)`. We can then use this metadata to find out which server is holding the key which we can access using

```
StreamsMetadata metadata = streams.metadataForKey(storeName, key, keySerializer);
metadata.host(); // gives us the server host
metadata.port(); // gives us the server port
```

We can use this data to make a call to the actual server that holds the value using REST call in my case. I am posting some snippets of the actual working code below.

Config

```
 @Bean
    public StreamsBuilder simpleKafkaStreamBuilder() throws UnknownHostException {
        final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

        KTable<String, Test> table1 = builder.stream(TEST_TOPIC, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()))
                .groupByKey()
                .aggregate(Test::new, this::aggregateData, materializeStoreV1());

        return builder;
    }

    private Materialized<String, Test, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>> materializeStoreV1() {
        return Materialized.<String, Test>as(Stores.inMemoryKeyValueStore(TEST_STORE1))
                .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
                .withValueSerde(testSerde());
    }

private Test aggregateData(String key, String value, Test test) {
        test.setKey(key);
        test.incrCount();
        return test;
    }
```

```
public static Properties getDefaultStreamProperties(){
        final Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, LOCAL_KAFKA_SERVER);
        props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "STREAMS_APP_");
        return props;
    }
```

RestController

```
@GetMapping("/start-streams")
    public void startStreams() throws UnknownHostException {
        Properties properties = SimpleKafkaUtil.getDefaultStreamProperties();
        properties.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_SERVER_CONFIG, InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress() + ":" + serverPort);
        properties.put(StreamsConfig.TOPOLOGY_OPTIMIZATION_CONFIG, StreamsConfig.OPTIMIZE);
        kafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(simpleKafkaStreamBuilder.build(properties), properties);
        System.out.println("[x] stream 1 " + kafkaStreams.toString());
        kafkaStreams.start();
    }

    @GetMapping("/access-store/{key}")
    public void accessStore(@PathVariable("key") String key) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("[x] stream 2 " + kafkaStreams.toString());
        while (!kafkaStreams.state().equals(KafkaStreams.State.RUNNING)){
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }

        List<StreamsMetadata> metadataList = (List<StreamsMetadata>) kafkaStreams.allMetadataForStore(SimpleKafkaConfig.TEST_STORE1);
metadataList.forEach(metadata -> {
        System.out.println(" [x] Host from list: " + metadata.host());
        System.out.println(" [x] Port from list: " + metadata.port());
});

        StreamsMetadata metadata = kafkaStreams.metadataForKey(SimpleKafkaConfig.TEST_STORE1, key, Serdes.String().serializer());
        System.out.println(" [x] Host: " + metadata.host());
        System.out.println(" [x] Port: " + metadata.port());

        String hostUri = "http://" + metadata.host() + ":" + metadata.port();

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        Test test = restTemplate.getForObject(hostUri + "/access-storeV2/" + key, Test.class);
        System.out.println("[x] KEY:" + key);
        System.out.println("[x] VALUE:" + test);
    }

    @GetMapping("/access-storeV2/{key}")
    public Test accessStoreV2(@PathVariable("key") String key) throws InterruptedException{
        System.out.println("[x] stream 2 " + kafkaStreams.toString());
        while (!kafkaStreams.state().equals(KafkaStreams.State.RUNNING)){
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }

        ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<String, Test> store = kafkaStreams.store(StoreQueryParameters.fromNameAndType(SimpleKafkaConfig.TEST_STORE1, QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore()));
        System.out.println("[x] Store KEY:" + key);
        System.out.println("[x] Store VALUE:" + store.get(key));
        return store.get(key);
    }
```

Comment: FWIW, most of this is already "configured" with https://www.azkarrastreams.io/